# Lookup JNDI names outside of java:comp/env on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I am working with an application originally designed for IBM WebSphere, but I want to also host it on Tomcat. The application cannot be changed, and is doing a `new InitialContext().lookup("servername")`, which works on WebSphere.

But on Tomcat, when I specify `<Environment>` names in the application specific context xml they are prefixed with `java:comp/env`, and the names aren't found by the above lookup.

It will run in a container, so there's no problem to update `server.xml` if I have to, and of course, the application specific context xml.

How can I get Tomcat to return a string on `lookup("servername")`?

Comment: Weird. The only thing I see in the [Tomcat source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/core/DefaultInstanceManager.java#L665) is actually *discarding* the `java:comp/env` prefix on any JNDI name. I see no place where it is *added*. It might be because Tomcat provides a bare-bones JNDI context and not the industrial-strength JNDI context provided by an EJB container.

Comment: Christopher, I believe it creates `java:comp/env` [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/ab583fac4efa3dd1edc36b1f9b42dbc2f5f314bf/java/org/apache/catalina/core/NamingContextListener.java#L534) and puts names into it [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/ab583fac4efa3dd1edc36b1f9b42dbc2f5f314bf/java/org/apache/catalina/core/NamingContextListener.java#L787).

Comment: Duh, I probably have not assumed that the whole string would be contiguous in the source :)

Comment: I'm trying to implement a custom `InitialContextFactory` as a workaround. I can get Tomcat to use it, but I haven't yet been able to get it to return a `Context` already at `java:comp/env`. If I can get it going I'll post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tomcat is hard-coded to behave in this way.

But it doesn't have to stay that way. Join the [Tomcat user's mailing list](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) and ask if there is a particular reason why things are the way they are. If there are no specific reasons to limit environment entries to the `java:comp/env` namespace, then I suspect a code change (probably involving a new configuration option) is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, I created this InitialContextFactory, which simply delegates the looking up of  String names to `System.getenv()` (Environment variables). This is very insecure, and will break apps which use naming properly, so I wouldn't recommend this for Production or outside of specific use cases. Or to any one at all really.

Nevertheless, by using this, I was able to get `(String) new InitialContext().lookup("servername")` to return a specific value `blah` via `set servername=blah` at the command line.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Binding;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NameParser;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory;

public class EnvironmentInitialContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {


    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?,?> environment) throws NamingException {

        return new Context() {

            public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {

                return System.getenv(name);

            }

            public Object lookup(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public void bind(Name name, Object obj) throws NamingException {}
            public void bind(String name, Object obj) throws NamingException {}
            public void rebind(Name name, Object obj) throws NamingException {}
            public void rebind(String name, Object obj) throws NamingException {}
            public void unbind(Name name) throws NamingException {}
            public void unbind(String name) throws NamingException {}
            public void rename(Name oldName, Name newName) throws NamingException {}
            public void rename(String oldName, String newName) throws NamingException {}
            public NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list(String name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public NamingEnumeration<Binding> listBindings(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public NamingEnumeration<Binding> listBindings(String name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public void destroySubcontext(Name name) throws NamingException {}
            public void destroySubcontext(String name) throws NamingException {}
            public Context createSubcontext(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }            
            public Context createSubcontext(String name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Object lookupLink(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Object lookupLink(String name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public NameParser getNameParser(Name name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public NameParser getNameParser(String name) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Name composeName(Name name, Name prefix) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public String composeName(String name, String prefix) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Object addToEnvironment(String propName, Object propVal) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Object removeFromEnvironment(String propName) throws NamingException { return null; }
            public Hashtable<?, ?> getEnvironment() throws NamingException { return null; }
            public void close() throws NamingException {}
            public String getNameInNamespace() throws NamingException { return null; }

        };

    }

}
```

Compile the class, and add it to the CLASSPATH and system properties, by adding these lines to `setenv.bat` (create in `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin/`):

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\path\to\compiled\class
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.naming.factory.initial=EnvironmentInitialContextFactory
```

Comment: If you just want to get the server name into the JVM, why not use a system property? `SET CATALINA_OPTS=-Dservername=foo` and then `System.getProperty`? That does not require any custom code.

Comment: Christopher, the application to be deployed is looking up with `(String) new InitialContext.lookup("servername")`, and can't be modified. The app was designed around hosting on WebSphere. So this question is all about how to deploy the same app on Tomcat in a way that the existing lookup returns a meaningful value.

Comment: Okay, that seams somewhat reasonable, then :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm revisiting this (I'm the asker). Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902296/9344362), I decided to implement a `ServletContextListener` instead.

In summary, you can't make Tomcat put the environment resources outside of `java:comp/env/` but you can read them from there and reassign them "wherever".

When the ServletContext is initialized, my listener just rebinds them:

```java
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ctx.bind("servername", ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/servername"));
    }
```

This is a much better solution - it doesn't fiddle with anything outside of the deployment context.

It's probably also possible to just rebind all names in the `comp/env/` namespace, to make a more generic listener. For now I am just binding the single names as there are few used by the app.